# How to hide my ActionBar

Tags: android

Here is my `ActionBar` related code :

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextHint)));

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); // To Show the Home Icon
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // To get the click Event of the
    // Home Button
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // To Unable Home Button to
    // work as a Navigation
    // Drawer Opener.

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    for (String tab_name : tabs)
    {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }

    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
```

I am getting this `ActionBar`

[image: I'm getting this]

But I want only this part as my `ActionBar` :

[image]

Thank you in advance for help & suggestion.

Comment: Use a `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar` and put whatever you'd like in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use these two lines

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);              
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

instead of

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom view for Action bar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.'id of custom layout');
setActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please read the question carefully and then answer. The question title is a bit confusing though.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the title of the question as the question is not about using customized `ActionBar` rather it points to hide the `ActionBar`.

The elegant way of doing this is to setting the theme of your `Activity` inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

So your `Activity` declaration in the manifest should look like this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

The style is given below. Put this in your `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And the other variant of the same style inside `res/values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Hope that helps!